# Remove a package that I download from website

Tags: apt, package-management, software-uninstall

I wanted to install paraview 5.11 and lookup some tutorial (the tutorial is in 5.9) in yt. He downloaded [package] from the website and proceed to unpack it to /opt/paraview-5.11 and then he make use of gedit to make a shortcut . I was following along but in the end i can't make a shortcut like he did. After that i was just checking `which paraview` but it returns nothing. this makes me curious, then i tried running it from terminal and it returns nothing too.

Furiously i typed `sudo apt-get install paraview` to my surprise it works...but it's 5.10 version. Now it appears on the menu, and i can execute it from terminal.

**The Question**

How do i remove the downloaded and unpacked Paraview 5.11 properly, now it's in my /opt/ folder

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should just remove the file you placed in `/opt`:

```
sudo rm /opt/paraview-5.11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the one you installed with apt:

```
sudo apt-get remove paraview
```

If you want to remove the one you downloaded to /opt:

```
sudo rm /opt/paraview*
```